# Printing Multiple Named Ranges to 1 PDF on Separate Sheets Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Instead of multiple sheets, I have different ranges that I'd like to print to a pdf.  How can I print the ranges depending on if shipYesNo = "Yes" or "No"?  I am struggling to figure out how to combine multiple exports of PDF named ranges (vs sheets which I've already seen).  At the very bottom I'm trying to combine the statements.  I also tried a union but had no luck with that.

Status Print and Ship Detail are the 2 ranges I'm referring to.

```
Public Function findLastRow(col As Range) As Long 'making the macro available to all Sub Procedures

        Dim lastRow As Long
        With col.Parent
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'finding the last possible row disregarding blanks
        End With

        findLastRow = lastRow

End Function

Public Sub Print_StatusPDF()

Dim Status_Print As Range
Dim Ship_Detail As Range
Dim Cust_Name As Range
Dim daterng As Range
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFileShipments As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim FilePath As String
Dim PrintSheets As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("Order_Status")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Shipment_Detail")
Set Status_Print = ws1.Range("B2:N" & findLastRow(ws1.Range("B9")))
Set Ship_Detail = ws2.Range("B1:G" & findLastRow(ws2.Range("G6")))
Set Cust_Name = Range("C5")
Set daterng = Sheets("Names").Range("date_range")
strFileName = Cust_Name & " Order Status " & daterng
strFileShipments = Cust_Name & " Shipment Detail "

'Setting the defined name range for printing
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Order_Print", RefersTo:=Status_Print
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Ship_Print", RefersTo:=Ship_Detail

'Autofitting the columns and setting them to center alignment
'Adjust this if columns are deleted/inserted
Range("B:M").Columns.AutoFit
Range("E:M").Columns.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

ws2.Range("B:H").Columns.AutoFit

'Setting the page setup options for printing
With Sheets("Order_Status").PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PrintArea = ws1.Range("Order_Print").Address
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .Zoom = False
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.36)
   .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
   .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
   .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
   .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
   .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    
End With

With ws2.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .PrintArea = ws2.Range("Ship_Print").Address
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .Zoom = False
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.36)
   .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
   .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
   .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
   .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
   .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    
End With


FilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
Debug.Print FilePath


'PrintSheets = Union(Status_Print, Ship_Detail)

'setting the location and name for where to print
'if shipYesNo = No then there's only the Staus_Print to print
If Sheets("Names").Range("shipYesNo").Value = "No" Then
Status_Print.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:= _
    FilePath & "\" & strFileName & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
'if shipYesNo = Yes then there are 2 ranges to print, with Status Print being on page 1 and Ship Detail on page 2
ElseIf Sheets("Names").Range("shipYesNo").Value = "Yes" Then:

Status_Print.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:= _
    FilePath & "\" & strFileName & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Ship_Detail.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:= _
    FilePath & "\" & strFileShipments & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you go a different route - use another worksheet to lay out a copy of all the data in one block and then just print that one block?

Comment: Is there a way to separate the blocks so they are each on 1 page ?